# Picking data randomly without a repeat in the index and create a new list out of it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

My program needs to pick values randomly without repeating them. After that, the program will assign them random variables.

Assume this is the data:

```
[input] data
[output]
                 0
0       770000.000
1       529400.000
2       780000.000
3       731300.000
4       935000.000
5       440000.000
6       634120.000
7       980000.000
8       600000.000
9       770000.000
10      600000.000
11      536613.000
12      660000.000
13      850000.000
14      563600.000
15      985000.000
16      600000.000
17      770000.000
18      957032.000
19      252000.000
20      397000.000
21      218750.000
22      785578.000
```

As you can see, the data contains repeated numbers in the index 0, 9, and 17. These numbers must not be ignored as the index is different.
I could not find any way to solve my problem. I had many attempts like using `data.iloc[0]`but, I recieved this

> error ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one
>   element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Or, in my other attempts, the data was reduced as the program excluded some similar data.

In my first attempt, I used the following code

```
Col_list = []    


def Grab(repeat):
        for x in range(FixedRange):


            letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
            Three = [random.choice(letters) + \
                     random.choice(letters) + \
                     random.choice(letters)]

            A_Slice = random.randint(1, Total_Range_of_Data)
            [Col_list.append(data[A_Slice:A_Slice + 200]),
            Col_list.append(Three*len(data[A_Slice:A_Slice + 200]))]
            Col_list1 = pd.DataFrame(Col_list).T
            Col_listFinal = Col_list1

Grab(0)
```

and the output will give something like

```
  .                 .                  .                    .
  .                 .                  .                    .
 190  1.06934e+06  kCn  3.46638e+06  EmV ...        514564  LLl       450000  hfX
 191       250000  kCn     1.37e+06  EmV ...   1.00430e+06  LLl       468305  hfX
 192       741088  kCn     1.25e+06  EmV ...        312032  LLl       520000  hfX
 193       427500  kCn       726700  EmV ...    1.0204e+06  LLl       495750  hfX
 194       969600  kCn       853388  EmV ...        139300  LLl       530000  hfX
 195       388556  kCn     1.21e+06  EmV ...        437500  LLl       598520  hfX
 196    2.045e+06  kCn  1.53636e+06  EmV ...        547835  LLl       538250  hfX
 197       435008  kCn       752700  EmV ...        712400  LLl       326000  hfX
 198  6.15566e+06  kCn  1.56282e+06  EmV ...     1.385e+06  LLl       480000  hfX
 199       551650  kCn    1.222e+06  EmV ...        771512  LLl       495750  hfX
```

But this is not helpful, as it is random and it may take some values more than once. Any suggestion to solve the problem?

by the way, the desired output must be something similar to the one above but without duplicates.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Similar to the output at the end of my post, but without duplicated values.

Comment: Could this be a job for `pandas.DataFrame.sample`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

Comment: Can you pick a _value_ twice, just not an _index location_ twice (or more)?

Comment: @Evan that is correct. Only the index is the one not repeated. Peter Leimbigler can this be looped??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @peter-leimbigler said, df.sample gets you most of the way there.

```
df.sample(10))

        data
4   935000.0
13  850000.0
20  397000.0
7   980000.0
22  785578.0
18  957032.0
19  252000.0
10  600000.0
5   440000.0
0   770000.0
```

This may repeat certain values, if those values exist at multiple index locations, but it shouldn't select the same index location more than once.

If you only want to sample unique values, you can use df[column].unique, although you can't sample that directly.

```
unique_series = df["data"].unique()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(unique_series), columns=["data"])

        data
0   770000.0
1   529400.0
2   780000.0
3   731300.0
4   935000.0
5   440000.0
6   634120.0
7   980000.0
8   600000.0
9   536613.0
10  660000.0
11  850000.0
12  563600.0
13  985000.0
14  957032.0
15  252000.0
16  397000.0
17  218750.0
18  785578.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pick random indices without replacement using `numpy.random.choice` with the `replace=False` keyword arg. Here's how you would pick `n` random values from `data` without repeated indices:

```
import numpy as np
drand = data.iloc[np.random.choice(np.arange(data.size), n, replace=False)]
```